# Linear transformations and possible dimension mismatch

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, linear-transformations

**The problem:** 
Let $L: R_4 \to R_3$ be defined by 
$$L([u_1, u_2 ,u_3 ,u_4]) = [u_1 ,(u_2+u_3), (u_3 + u_4)]$$
Let S and T be the natural bases for $R_4$ and $R_3$, respectively.
Find the representation of L with respect to S and T.

**My answer:** 
The bases for S and T are just $I_4$ and $I_3$, respectively. Now transforming S I find easy because S has four vectors in it. However, what am I supposed to do with T? It only goes up to $u_3$, not $u_4$. Do I attach a row of zeros to make it have four vectors, or is this type of transformation impossible? By the way, my answer for the transformation of S is:

$$L(S) = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: You don't want a square matrix, you want the input to be a $4$ vector and the output to be a $3$ vector.

Comment: Your resulting matrix must be of the form $(L(e_1)|L(e_2)|L(e_3)|L(e_4))$ where $e_i$ are the basis vectors in $S$. Express the images $L(e_i)$ with respect to the basis $T$. In conclusion, your matrix is correct. There's nothing more to do.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Okay, which that works for S, but T only has 3 vectors.

Comment: @t808: $T$ is the basis in which you're supposed to express the resulting vectors $L(e_i)$. For example $L(e_1) = L(1,0,0,0) = (1,0,0) = e_1^{'}$. Where $e_1^{'} = (1,0,0)$ is a basis vector in $T$ and $e_1 = (1,0,0,0)$ is in $S$.

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette That matrix form you have ... do the "|" separators mean "start a new row?" Also, is the phrase "with respect to S and T" mean one starts working with S and after the transformation it matches with T automatically if T is the natural basis, but one has to do a little more work if T is not the natural basis? I was trying to "plug in" S, to get one answer, then plug in T to get another answer, but I can start to see that this phrase of "S and T" do not mean separate answers.

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette Thanks for the example, you saw what I was thinking before I could post it! Thanks!

Comment: The $|$ mean "start a new column". Maybe look up the definition of the transformation matrix on wikipedia. Yes, it's true that if $T$ wasn't the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you would (usually) have to do some more work.